# Clean URLs with PHP

Tags: php, http, url, url-mapping

So I am trying to build a clean url system in PHP to change URLS like this `http://example.com/index.php?projects=05` to: `http://example.com/projects/05`

So far, I have figured out how to use `parse_url` to map urls that look like `http://example.com/index.php/projects/05` but I can't figure out how to remove the 'index.php' from the URL. Is there a way to use .htaccess to remove `index.php` from the url string?

I know this is sort of a simple problem but after extensive googling, I can't find a solution.

Comment: You should use mod rewrite in .htaccess for turning /index.php to /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this in Apache using mod_rewrite. You'll need to redirect all URLs to to your index.php and then, maybe using parse_url, figure out what to do with them.

For example:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Only redirect if the request is not for index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

# and the request is not for an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# or an actual folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# finally, rewrite (not redirect) to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Im having trouble finding a way to automatically redirect using .htaccess - can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following .htaccess file to remove the index.php part of the url.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Otherwise I can recommend the Kohana framework as a reference (they also have a fairly nice url parser and controller system)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

(Be sure the rewrite module is enabled)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of decoupling the actual files/folders from the URL is called *routing*. Many PHP frameworks include this kind of functionality, mostly using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/). There is a nice blog post on [PHP URL Routing](http://josephscott.org/archives/2008/11/php-url-routing-pur/) that implements a simple standalone router class.

It creates mapping like this:

```
mysite.com/projects/show/1 --> Projects::show(1)
```

So the requested URL results in the function `show()` of the class `Projects` being called, with the parameter of `1`.

You can use this to build flexible mappings of pretty URLs to your PHP code.